# What is the box size of this very valuable 1957 French Monopoly set?

Tags: monopoly

The cover of a French 1957 Monopoly set (see picture) appears in two web sites.
It was evaluated at $2,456 on one website,
[workandmoney.com](https://www.workandmoney.com/s/valuable-vintage-board-games-32b5423591a94861) and estimated for auction at £2,000 on another website [dailymail.co.uk](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-6114471/Antique-expert-reveals-vintage-board-games-fetch-90-000.html).

[image: 1957 French Monopoly]

There are two types of Monopoly white box sets, a long one, and a smaller, square one, more in use in Europe, in which the board is folded in four squares; the long one was sometimes also used in France.

Is there a means of determing which of the box sizes is that of this very valuable 1957 French Monopoly set?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to find additional images of the same box, which is a little difficult, but not impossible:

[image: French Monopoly]
[image: French Monopoly box contents]

Based on that we can surmise that the box is square.

Comment: Incorrect. The photograph of this very box is on the Monopoly Fandom page https://monopoly.fandom.com/wiki/French_Edition. It is clearly a 1960 edition and the one the question is about is a 1857 edition.

Comment: Well that's just plain wrong, the non-leather 1960 edition from Miro was updated to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/szA7O.png

Comment: Additional to that, seeing as that same edition was published between 1940 and 1960 I would be surprised if the value really was so high, rather it's more likely a particular copy of some significance was sold. Unfortunately I have also found zero evidence of such a sale being made.

Comment: Even the stain on the bottom right side of the 1960 box (in https://monopoly.fandom.com/wiki/French_Edition) is identical to the one in your photograph.

Comment: It's definitely the same photo, it's just not of a edition printed in 1960, based on when they printed boxes in that style it could actually be from anytime between 1935 and 1959.

Comment: @RobertMiller 1857?

Comment: That's probably why it's so valuable... ;)